# Angular 6 vendor and main js taking too much time to load the data

Tags: angular, angular6

I dont understand why in my project scripting is taking too much time to load the page. It look like angular 6 is taking time in loading css and js from assest folder as well its taking time to load vendor and main js. I dont understand why its happening. 
[image: see this screenshot]

below is my routing file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { TeamCardComponent } from './team-card/team-card.component';
import { TeamComponent } from './team/team.component';
import { TeamDetailsComponent } from './team-details/team-details.component';
import { PipelineComponent } from './pipeline/pipeline.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { LeadsComponent } from './leads/leads.component';
import { TestpopupComponent } from './testpopup/testpopup.component';
import { CreateleadComponent } from './createlead/createlead.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { CreateTeamComponent } from './create-team/create-team.component';
import { CreatePipelineComponent } from './create-pipeline/create-pipeline.component';
import { PipelineDetailsComponent } from './pipeline-details/pipeline-details.component';
import { FormValidationComponent } from './form-validation/form-validation.component';
import { AssociateDashboardComponent } from './associate-dashboard/associate-dashboard.component';
import { AssociateProfileComponent } from './associate-profile/associate-profile.component';
import { AssociateProductComponent } from './associate-product/associate-product.component';
import { AssociateCalendarComponent } from './associate-calendar/associate-calendar.component';
import { AssociateLeadComponent } from './associate-lead/associate-lead.component';
import { TwilioVideoComponent } from './twilio-video/twilio-video.component';
import { CreateUpdateProductComponent } from './create-product-new/create-product-new.component';
import { UnAuthenticatedTaskListComponent } from './un-authenticated-task-list/un-authenticated-task-list.component';
import { ProductSignalDemoComponent } from './product-signal-demo/product-signal-demo.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'app', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'teams', component: TeamComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'teamdetail/:id', component: TeamDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'pipeline', component: PipelineComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'leads', component: LeadsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'testpopup', component: TestpopupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'createlead', component: CreateleadComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'createteam', component: CreateTeamComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'create-pipeline', component: CreatePipelineComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'pipeline-details/:id', component: PipelineDetailsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  // { path: 'form-validation', component: FormValidationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'dashboard-associate', component: AssociateDashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'profile-associate', component: AssociateProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'product-associate', component: AssociateProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'calendar-associate', component: AssociateCalendarComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'lead-associate', component: AssociateLeadComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'twilio-video', component: TwilioVideoComponent },
  { path: 'productedit/:productId', component: CreateUpdateProductComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'demo', component: UnAuthenticatedTaskListComponent },
  { path: 'signals', component: ProductSignalDemoComponent },
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my index.html code for loading css and js

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tant</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/ngselect.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/dropzone.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/all.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-family-Lato.css" />
  <link href="../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">


  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
    crossorigin="anonymous"> -->


  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
</head>

<body class="background position-relative">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="assets/js/twilio.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/twilio.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

I am loading css and js from asset folder but still its taking 23-30 second to load the page which is too much.

[image: scripting image]

I have a single module and multiple component project. Even if i comment my logic empty component is taking 10 seconds for loading css and js. Event after caching css and js its taking 8 seconds for displaying an empty component. What should i do please suggest

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to incorrect web-pack bundling. so please do this

```
1.just open the package.json, 
2.modify the "devDependencies" section,
3.add line "webpack-sources": "1.2.0",
```

then yarn or npm update

and other thing is you need to lazy load components. sometimes it can't logically group in to modules but the seek of loading and performance you have to do it. then main.js size will be break and loaded on demand .

also try to compile with --aot and it will give you a huge impact on performance

Comment: I did this page loading time is less but its increasing CPU utilisation that too above 100% when compile with AOT

Comment: in my case it wont go beyond 20%.... so it may be due to system cause .. if you have windows 10 then it has 100% CPU problem. it happened to me when i use angular 4 with --prod . so please check that out (my spec : Intel i3 4 th gen , 8 gb Ram... )

Comment: But even in production mode it's showing 50% of cput for empty components

Comment: Yeah I m on windows 10. What should I do

Comment: Follow these notes please 
https://fossbytes.com/how-to-fix-high-ram-and-cpu-usage-of-windows-10-system-ntoskrnl-exe-process/

also use a good scanner and scan the system for attached viruses.

Comment: Problem is my users is using it on windows 10 how can I do it on their machine.

Comment: No this steps has to do in your development PC's . you just don't worry about end users. when you build angular app with --Aot flag it will give you a folder name DIST. it contains pure javascript files. so when you host them in a web server then the application will be supper fast. now you doing is JIT build . so typescrpit to Javascipt transpile commence in the browser . that's why it too slow.

Comment: I run ng build --aot --prod but still scripting is taking 12-13 seconds :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184614/discussion-between-h-a-neo-and-feroz-siddiqui).